# PowerShell and Robocopy - filename incorrect when trying to pass variable folder as destination

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to use a PowerShell script running Robocopy`*` to back some files up to a newly-made directory:

```
$Timestamp = Get-Date -format ddMMyyyy

$DestFolder = "`"\\NASBOX\Archives\$Timestamp\`""
$SourceFolder = "`"\\DESKTOP\d$`""

ROBOCOPY $SourceFolder $DestFolder /COPYALL /B /R:10 /W:90 /LOG:$Timestamp.txt /FP /TEE
```

This gives me the following error:

```
2018/01/23 16:26:20 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Destination Directory \\NASBOX\Archives\23012018" \COPYALL \B \R:10 \W:90 \LOG:23012018.txt \FP \TEE\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I've tried a few different methods, including passing the arguments as an array. Every single thing I've tried results in the exact same error.

I roughly understand why this is happening, but despite ~two hours spent online I can't find a solution that works in my specific context.

Where am I going wrong?

`*` I tried using Copy-Item but there are some super long directory paths on this desktop's "D" drive.

Comment: Your error has a quote at the the end of the folder without a matching open quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the trailing slash in the path you are building:

```
"\\NASBOX\Archives\23012018\"
```

This slash is escaping the double quote for robocopy, it is seeing this path as including a quote symbol at the end :

```
\\NASBOX\Archives\23012018"
```

The error message shows this, but isn't very helpful! To fix the issue, simply remove the trailing slash from your path:

```
$DestFolder = "`"\\NASBOX\Archives\$Timestamp`""
```

Comment: The "quote escaping" is not necessary. Just put the paths in the variables, use those variables on the `robocopy` command line, and PowerShell will quote when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to try so hard with escaping of quotes in your variables. PowerShell handles most of this for you. This should be all you need to do:

```
$Timestamp = Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy

$SourceFolder = "\\DESKTOP\d$"
$DestFolder = "\\NASBOX\Archives\$Timestamp"

ROBOCOPY $SourceFolder $DestFolder /COPYALL /B /R:10 /W:90 /LOG:$Timestamp.txt /FP /TEE
```

Note that the destination folder shouldn't include a trailing `\`.

TL;DR - It is not necessary to create strings with embedded `"` characters to pass to `robocopy`. Just put the variables on the `robocopy` command line and PowerShell will quote automatically when necessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function Copy-File {
    [CmdletBinding()]   
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [string]$source,
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [string]$dest,
        [Parameter(Position=2)]
        [string]$sourcefile,
        [Parameter(Position=3)]
        [ref]$RoboError
        )
    Write-Log -message "Copying $sourcefile from $source to $dest"
    $robotoday=(Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
    $logfile = -join($env:systemdrive, '\logs\', $robotoday, '_robocopy.log')
    $what = @("$sourcefile",'/COPY:DAT', '/Z', '/E')
    $options = @("/R:1","/W:1","/TEE","/ETA","/LOG+:$logfile")
    $cmdArgs = @($source,$dest,$what,$options)
    robocopy @cmdArgs
    if ($lastexitcode -gt 7) {
        $RoboError.value=$TRUE
        Write-Log -level 'warn' -message "Robocopy function failed with error: $lastexitcode"
    }
} # End Copy-File

[bool]$RoboError=$FALSE
Copy-File -source $copysource -dest $copydestination -sourcefile '*' -RoboError([ref]$RoboError)
```